# How to create a user defined function in PHP exactly the same as str_replace(), without using any other built-in functions except for strlen()

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo my_string_replace("world","jonathan","hello world helloworld");

function my_string_replace($find, $replace, $string)
{
//Block of codes here...
}
?>
```

I can only use loops, if else statements, and other commands such as break and continue. I want to create my own algorithm. Please help me. This should output : hello jonathan hellojonathan"

Comment: Why would you? But then, if you insist: a string in php can be treated like an array. So `$replace[0]` would output `j` and `$string[1]` would output `e`. Loop over the string, comparing letters, find your match and replace the letters.

Comment: yes . i have been thinking about the algorithm but i cant solve it.
i have also tried searching for codes but i cant find any

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: @JohnConde : This is just my school homework that I'm trying to solve. I have already done trying to make my own code and algorithm but I can't solve it. I have also tried researching here but they are using built-in functions other than strlen(), so i posted and asked.
Thanks anyway sir.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was a fun brain teaser. Here you go:

```
echo my_string_replace("world", "jonathan", "hello world helloworld");

function my_string_replace($find, $replace, $string)
{
    $characterCount = strlen($string);
    $findCount      = strlen($find);
    $replaceCount   = strlen($replace);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $characterCount - $findCount +1; $i++) {
        if ($string[$i] == $find[0]) {
            $j     = 1;
            $found = true;
            while ($j < $findCount) {
                if ($string[$i + $j] != $find[$j]) {
                    $found = false;
                    break;
                }
                $j++;
            }
            if ($found) {
                // copy string until current position
                $replaced = '';
                for ($x = 0; $x < $i; $x++) {
                    $replaced .= $string[$x];
                }
                // append replacement
                $replaced .= $replace;
                // copy after match till end
                for ($x = $i + $findCount; $x < $characterCount; $x++) {
                    $replaced .= $string[$x];
                }
                // continue with replaced string, after replacement
                $string         = $replaced;
                $characterCount = strlen($string);
                $i              = $i + $replaceCount;
            }
        }
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: This is the exact solution I've been thinking.
Thank you so much.
I've been thinking of this for nights lol.
Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(0);` used for hide "Uninitialized string offset" notice.

```
    <?php 
   function str_v2($num){
        error_reporting(0);    
        for($i=0; $num[$i] != "";$i++);
        echo $i; }//end of function
        $name = "Hope this will work.";
        echo str_v2($name);     
?>
```